# how to use cd command in powershell

Tags: powershell

How would I use the cd command from the current directory to go back two directories and run a script?

I'm running a script that is located in server\test1.ps1
I need to go two directories from the server folder and there is a folder called setup. I need to run test2.ps1 from setup. test2 is called from within test1 script.
here is the folder structure

(I need to give test2.ps1 path here in test1 script)

```
scripts/server/test/test1.ps1  
scripts/backup/test/test2.ps1
```

I'm using something like this but its not working

```
.\..\backup\test\test2.ps1
```

Answer (score 3):

The short answer should be

```
..\..\backup\test\test2.ps1
```

`.` is current directory and `..` is the parent. You want to navigate up two parent folders.

For a PowerShell answer, which is more wordy than just `..\..\`, that would return the folder two levels up relative to the current location. This is mostly provided for fun. `Split-Path` with no switches other than a path will return the full path of the parent folder.

```
Split-Path (Split-Path (Get-Location).Path)
```

Answer (score -1):

Most command lines work from the simple window cmd rather than PowerShell. I had the same problem and finally exited the PowerShell and run the command from cmd and it worked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34727929)